# Vuelidate does not work correctly when the data model is different from validations model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuelidate

When the data model is different from validations model, required and minLength are not validating correctly.
https://jsfiddle.net/2vs9kdb3/4/

```
<input v-model="text" @blur="$v.form.text.$touch()" :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.form.text.$error }">
<template v-if="!$v.form.text.minLength">
    Text is too short
</template>


....


data: {
    text: ''
},

validations: {
    form: {
        text: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(5)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not stated in the docs the `validations` structure must be the same as the `data` model.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the convention.
first: use

```
data: {
 form: { text: '' }
}
```

and also use v-model="$v.form.text.$model".